# Assigning values Struct to Struct in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, struct

I'm pretty new to SwiftUI. and I'm facing some kind of errors while I tried to do this.I have two SwiftUI File of struct like

```
 struct UserOne: Students {
       let id: Int
       var name: String?
       var controllerUID: String?
       }
 extension UserOne: Codable {
       enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case id                 = "_id"
           case name
       }
}
 


struct UserTwo: <Z: Students> {
           let UID: String
           var name: String?
           var controllerUID: String?
           var bar: [Z]?
           }
     extension UserTwo: Codable {
           enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
               case UID                 = "_uid"
               case name
               case bar                 = "_bar"
           }
    }



 struct User: College {
   let id: Int
   var name: String?
   var controllerUID: String?
   }
extension User: Codable {
   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case id             = "id"
       case name           = "name"
   case controllerUID      = "controllerUID"
   }
}





typealias Students: College & Two & Three {
protocol College: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int { get }
    var name: String? { get set }
var controllerUID: String? { get }

}
..........so on


Struct: Device {
var name: String
var UID: String?
}
 extension Device: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case UID                    = "UID"
        case name                   = "NAME"
}
extension Device: Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        UID
    }
}

extension Device: Hashable { }
```

so here I have added **three struct SwiftUI files** which having names **UserOne, UserTwo and Device** and also one **typealise of Students having protocol College.** so first I'm looking for **Struct UserTwo** has an **case name** which leads to the **string name** having nil value. but I need to display their value.so for that by using the **Device Struct** it has **name and UID** same things like **UserTwo** also has. if their the **UID** is matching the display the **Device name string to the UserTwo name string**.

and the second one I have required is in **Struct UserOne the name** value is nil. so I need the **Struct User name string value** to display over the **Struct UserOne name**. this can be done by checking if **ControllerUID** in both **Struct User** and **UserOne** and also matching the **id** are same then display the **User name** string value to the **UserOne name** string value.

but here in Struct UserOne the value of controllerUID is nil it is added by just to ensure the typealise of Students protocol College value.but the ControllerUID in the Struct User, UserOne, UserTwo and protocol is same if all have values.

so far for first thing I have tried this but it is not working

```
 mutating func updateNameIfNeeded(from devices: [Device]) {
           guard name == nil else { return }
           
           if let matchingDevice = devices.first(where: { $0.UID == UID }) {
               name = matchingDevice.name
           }
       }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with SwiftUI. And the code doesn't compile (beside the wrong upper and lowercase) because the protocol requirement  of `id` is a **non-optional `Int`**.

Comment: yeah. you are correct I mistakenly coded there string. now can you check?@vadian

Comment: Your code is still not correct swift code and also add the code that you have tried, that causes the issue, to the question.

Comment: The updated code has errors (again). Please get it working in Xcode first, then paste it to your question. You could also use Xcode to format the code in a more standard way - select it all and press ```Ctrl/I```. If the problem is, that you are not able to define the structs as you want them, then please at least highlight the errors that you know about but are not able to resolve. From the updated description, some examples of actual data might also help to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to understand your question. Your code has some bizarre uppercase/lowercase errors and I don't see why "Struct B name has values" when it is an optional string just the same as A.

But here goes. Maybe you want an instance of struct `A` to deliver the string optional that has been set on an instance of struct `B`? This cannot be solved using inheritance, because structs cannot have subclasses. But it could be solved using composition and delegation. Like this:

```swift
protocol One: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int { get }
    var name: String? { get set }
}

protocol Two: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int { get }
    var flag: Bool { get set }
}

protocol Three: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int { get }
    var val: Int { get set }
}

struct B: One {
    let id: Int
    var name: String?
}

typealias MY = One & Two & Three

struct A: MY {
    let id: Int
    var myB: B
    var name: String? { // protocol One
        get { myB.name }
        set { myB.name = newValue }
    }
    var flag: Bool // protocol Two
    var val: Int // protocol Three
}
```

If this is not what you were trying to achieve then perhaps you could please fix the code in the question to make it *complete* and see that it *compiles properly*. Then please also update the question itself to explain more clearly what you want to get working, ideally with an example of what is not currently working. Thanks.

Comment: thank you. like my purpose is struct A variables are the storing keyword of api response. and under this struct it has an codable case extension for this keywords.and under this api response there is no name value it is nill.

Comment: so I need to take the name value from struct B to struct A. that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: can you understand what I'm looking.?

Comment: So A is missing a value, but B has it? Can you maybe use a nil-coalescing operator to read the name from B as a fallback: ```name = a.name ?? b.name``` ? For more help, you really need to make the code in the question more *complete* and perhaps provide some examples of actual data and usage. At the moment, we're still trying to guess how the structs are being used and what the actual issue is.

Comment: ok.i will edit my question to some actual things to underastand.

Comment: I have edited my question with all details and I have explained what I have needed here.

Answer (score 0):

With typealias and protocol, you are only defining relationship but not automatically assign values. For that you may use for loop to assign values from struct B to A with conditions such as `if structA.name == nil`